# Can I go back and change a line I echoed previously in Bash?

Tags: bash, curl

I've seen some applications do this and I think it has to do with curl. Is it possible to do something like this in a shell script?

For example, making a spinner:

```
[/]
[-]
[\]
```

But have it keep spinning on the same line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [CSI escape sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#CSI_sequences) :

```
CHARACTERS='- \\ - /'
echo -ne '[/]\e[2D'
while true; do
    for char in $CHARACTERS; do
        sleep 1
        echo -ne "$char\\e[1D"
    done
done
```

The first echo writes `[/]` then moves the cursor back over the `/` with "CUB – Cursor Back" with a travel length parameter of 2 columns.
In the while loop we overwrite the middle character with each successive value it should take, going back over it with "CUB – Cursor Back" with a travel length parameter of 1 column.